# How can I get IntelliSense for SVG in HTML, CSS, and JS in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, svg

How can I get in VS Code autocomplete / suggestions for  words like **svg, circle** etc. . ? I have few extension like Auto Close Tag but that doesn't work.

In JavaScript, it doesn't autocomplete `.style.strokeDasharray`, `.style.strokeDashoffset`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As for support in JavaScript, I get suggestions for `.style.strokeDashArray` just fine. Probably you just are missing type annotations on your things. You can use JSDoc comments like this:

```js
/** @type {SVGElement} */
let foo = /* value */;
foo.style.stroke // <- trigger suggestions here
```

If the `SVGElement` type is inferrable from context (VS Code's builtin JavaScript IntelliSense is powered by TypeScript itself), then it may be inferred, in which case you won't need to write the type annotation. For example, if you initialize a variable with the return value of a function which is type-annotated to return an `SVGElement`.

---

For the HTML and CSS support, this is an open issue. See [[css][html] SVG language support #66053](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66053). Give it a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

Comment: with /** @type {SVGElement} */ it work perfectly. Is there some reason why I need add this comment block ? Can I use suggestions without this comment ?